# What was the most inconsequential failure on an STS mission recorded in mission reports?

Tags: space-shuttle, failure

Posting a comment over on [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/61042/29286) got me thinking as to how insignificant (or not) recorded failures on the Space Shuttle could actually get.

For example browsing the [STS-001 Postflight Mission Report](https://archive.org/details/48011357STS1OrbiterFinalMissionReport) yields:

- Flight test problem report 20 (page 189): Squeal in crews headsets
  (There was acoustic feedback, and not having both the headset microphone *and* speaker-microphone unit activated simultaneously fixed it)
- Flight test problem report 40 (page 211): Crew reported trouble locking doors on two stowage lockers
  (They basically still forced them shut)

**What recorded problem had the least negative or potentially negative impact on the mission?**

Comment: You missed the best part of the door snag... "The slide bolt on the waste management door jammed when latched," meaning somebody almost got stuck in the toilet.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's a good one!

Wow, what to pick: stuck locker doors, slightly hazed windows, problems with the galley.

How about a Velcro problem?

> The
> EDFT-03
> utility
> box evaluation
> resulted
> in a Velcro
> patch on the connector cover becoming loose (Flight Problem STS-72-F-08).
> The Velcro
> patch was brought into the cabin
> at the end of the EVA.

EDFT was the "EVA Development Flight Test" project, intended to try out EVA procedures before Space Station construction commenced.  EDFT-03 was a box of connectors and plugs for the crew to evaluate during EVA, located in the payload bay. (Highlighted below). You can see white Velcro patches on the square tubing towards the rear of the box.

[image]

Image source: [images.nasa.gov](https://images.nasa.gov/details/STS072-722-041), annotations mine

And yes, I get that loose stuff floating around in the payload bay could cause problems. But still.

References:

- [STS-072 Press Kit](https://www.scribd.com/document/44352091/STS-72-Press-Kit)
- [STS-072 Post Flight Mission Report](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19970001262/downloads/19970001262.pdf)

Per request, a closeup of the utility box with Velcro patches pointed out.

[image]

Comment: I'll wait a bit before accepting an answer. In the meantime do you have example mission numbers for the slightly hazed windows or problems with the galley?

Comment: @Speedphoenix oh yeah, definitely wait, maybe someone will come up with a stale tortilla problem or something.  Hazed windows were epidemic, try STS-048 for an example. Galley also. A galley water leak "that did not impact the use of the galley in any manner" was on STS-038.

Comment: It occurs to me that not having a Velcro patch in an expected place could, in the general case, cause future problems. Attaching something to a Velcro patch which subsequently floated away definitely would. And a headset squeal might be significant if- unknown to the users- people working on the equipment were trying to minimise that specific problem.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd I don't disagree. And window haze could be bad if lighting conditions were such that it affected viewing through the window at a critical point in landing. I picked the Velcro to try and match the lighthearted tone of the question, and because Velcro was kind of a humorous *bete noire* of mine - it seemed that whenever I really, really needed to get into the simulator to check something out, it was reserved for a "Velcro mod" session. Check out all the blue Velcro https://www.nasa.gov/images/content/650294main_powerdown-cockpit.jpg

Comment: Window haze might also be a sign of some other more serious problem, e.g. something is leaking somewhere, causing condensation to accumulate?  Or the window pane has been compromised in some way (Material stress? Heat from previous reentries?  Micrometeorites or debris strikes?)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman it was typically caused by combustion products released by the solid rocket boosters at separation. Late in the program, they implemented a change to fire the up-firing nose jets at separation, which produced a shock pattern that mostly kept the products from depositing on the windows. See page 21 here https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20090011844/downloads/20090011844.pdf

Comment: @OrganicMarble We are, of course, at risk of forgetting the mandatory ™ and ® symbols in our discussion of a certain brand of hook-and-loop fastener :-) Although I'm aware of some heavy-handed behaviour when it comes to protecting e.g. Swiss Army Knives.

Comment: Maybe I'm just old or tired, and I just randomly clicked this question and don't know a lot about the shuttle construction, but can you highlight more specifically, maybe with an arrow?  Even zooming in, I'm not sure what's square tubing or a box, much less velcro.

Comment: @user34314 done

Comment: @OrganicMarble Were you supplied with a tube of UHU glue (or similar) to stick things back down?